# create a report from msinfo32.exe via ruby

Tags: ruby, executable, msinfo32

I would like to silently save out a report from msinfo32.exe using ruby. How can I do so? I tried the following

```
system "msinfo32.exe /\report c:/\/\temp/\/\fromruby.txt"
exec 'msinfo32.exe /\report c:/\/\temp/\/\fromruby.txt'
IO.popen("msinfo32.exe /\report c:/\/\temp/\/\fromruby.txt")
```

and all of these open the application instead of silently creating the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
system "msinfo32.exe /\report c:/\/\temp/\/\fromruby.txt"
                      ^^           ^^
```

`\r` is a carriage return, `\t` is a tab character, and `\f` is a formfeed. none of those have to be escaped at all in the first place.

so instead of executing a single command:

```
msinfo32.exe /report c:\temp\fromruby.txt
```

you're executing all of these separate commands:

```
msinfo32.exe /
eport c://        temp//
romruby.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. After removing the escapes the system command works. However exec and IO.open fails with "Access Denied" message...but as system works I am good.....Thank you very much.